# How should we take the sum of values in a column after grouping by a different column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-analysis

I am trying to plot a graph for to analyze if there's any relation between the available_days of a property and number of reviews for it. I have a dataset which has different unique property listings, available_days for each property, number of reviews for each property. I am trying to plot by grouping the data by 'available_days' and I need to count the total number of reviews for those properties. For example, if the available days are 25, then I need to take the sum of the number of reviews for all properties with 25 available days. I couldn't figure out a way to do this. I tried as below but it is not giving me the expected result.

```
available_days=listings.groupby(['availability_365']).count()
available_days=listings.groupby(['availability_365'])['reviews_count'].count()
available_days=listings.groupby('availability_365').agg('sum')
available_days=listings.groupby(['availability_365']).agg({'reviews_count':np.sum})
```

Here is the dataset I am referring to:[image: dataset]

This is the desired output format:
[image: desired_output]

Also, please suggest a better way of approaching this problem to plot the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "availability": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    "num_reviews": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
})

# Count number of reviews per unique value for "availibility"
df["reviews_by_availability"] = df.groupby("availability")["num_reviews"].transform("sum")
print df

# Optionally, print only one instance of each "availability"
print df.drop_duplicates(subset=["availability"])
```

Output:

```
   availability  num_reviews  reviews_by_availability
0             1            1                        1
1             2            1                        2
2             2            1                        2
3             3            1                        3
4             3            1                        3
5             3            1                        3
6             4            1                        4
7             4            1                        4
8             4            1                        4
9             4            1                        4
   availability  num_reviews  reviews_by_availability
0             1            1                        1
1             2            1                        2
3             3            1                        3
6             4            1                        4
```

Also, please don't post images of your data, that's not helpful at all.

**EDIT:** You can plot it with `pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter()`:

```
# Draw scatterplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df.drop_duplicates(subset=["availability"]).plot.scatter(x="availability", y="reviews_by_availability")
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image: Plot result]